# What is this "shadow" called and what's the purpose?

Tags: screen, user-interface

When you slide Chrome browser (or FireFox) to extreme left, right or upwards, you see this *shadow* (for want of a better word) for a few seconds, as shown

[image]
[image]

**What is it called and what's the purpose ?** (Can't Google since I don't know what it is :)

It's on Moto X Play and it's not the *jelly scrolling* reported on some recent phones

Comment: I can see this happening to other apps, such as Stack Exchange itself and the Nova Launcher. Curiously, the phenomenon does not manifest itself inside "rétro" apps such as K-9 Mail, therefore I'm tempted to define it as an aesthetical quirk of Google's Material Design.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This appears to be called [EdgeEffect](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EdgeEffect.html) and is used [as a visual indicator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11489212/4720957) when the user over-scrolls.

- See relevant images on Google Images [here](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+edge+effect&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIwJPM8-3VAhVJP48KHVk5AqIQsAQIUA&biw=1366&bih=675).
- A [book](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=cEytznnRkikC&pg=PT313&lpg=PT313&dq=edgeeffect+android+explained&source=bl&ots=hBLB091zjv&sig=xQpRgw0gcSTo4lKARVPT9RTemIE&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT-6Cm9O3VAhUIrY8KHW29AC0Q6AEIVzAJ#v=onepage&q=edgeeffect%20android%20explained&f=false) commenting on the glow effect produces.
- A question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27104521/android-lollipop-scrollview-edge-effect-color).

Answer (score 9):

As suggested already, this graphical "shadow" effect is **Edge Glow colour**, and its part of the material design by Google.

> After the introduction of material design by Google many new UI elements have been introduced. Material design is based on the interaction and movement of colours and objects in real world rather than synthetic unnatural phenomenon. Sometimes it gets messy when we try to keep up with our material aesthetic. The most popular example of it is edge glow colour.

The effect was introduced in the ice cream sandwich (api 14) android version. Its part of Material design's aesthetic appeal.
The edge glow colour of ListView, RecyclerView, ScrollView and NestedScrollView is managed by the accent colour declared in the styles.

[Source](http://blog.fossasia.org/managing-edge-glow-color-in-nested-scrollview-in-open-event-android-app/)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it's purpose was to replace https://duckduckgo.com/apple+rubber+band+patent without being suable?

https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html recommends the OverScroller for giving better feedback