# How to disable EdgeEffect when over-scrolling?

Tags: customization

When you have only one home screen or scroll past the start or end of multiple  home screens, EdgeEffect appears, as shown on the left in the image. Can this be disabled?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: It is called [EdgeEffect](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/181869/96277).

Comment: Thanks , I searched and searched and never found that name