# Chome flag "Overscroll history navigation" by default

Tags: chrome-for-android

I have casually found this feature without having enabled anything in

*chrome://flags*.

Suddenly the option has disappeared.

Why this behaviour? I don't understand why the feature was enabled, and I can't see why it suddenly has disabled (I've found *Default* mode checked in *flags* section).

EDIT
Chrome version 81.0.4044.96

Comment: To answer why enabled or disabled - these are experimental features as you can see when you type `Chrome://flags`. If they want to make it a permanent feature or not is upto then. User has no choice// Coming to the flag you are concerned about, in all the options *except* disabled, overscroll is there. [Related question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/181869/131553)

Comment: @beeshyams So, being the option *Default*, it was there from installation. I don't understand however why it has stopped working. Perhaps because indeed it is experimental? Some flags have checked Default, others have Disabled; the picture is very heterogeneous

Comment: *Experimental* is the operative factor //Being experimental how can one have any predictability or coherent view?//Besides you are on old version. I am on 86.x updated from Play store